# Is it possible to call 'this' recursively in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is it possible to call the nameless callback function of an asynchronous function recursively within that function?

This is pseudo code but the idea is that I want re-call a failed http request.

```
function(err, res) { //parent callback
    request.get(URL, function(err, res) {
        if (err == 209) { //call the nameless parent function but how?
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If the anonymous function is assigned to a variable, then yes, you can call it by referring to the variable.

Comment: If it's anonymous and you don't have a reference to it, then no it's impossible.

Comment: Somebody should post a y-combinator answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this with a nameless function, but why not give it a name?

```
function doRequest(err, res) {
  request.get(URL, function(err, res) {
      if (err==209) {
          doRequest();
      }
  });
}
```

You can still use this function as an inline callback the same way as you'd use an anonymous function, it just happens to have a name.  For example:

```
setTimeout(function doRequest(err, res) { ... }, 200 );
```

Or if you're calling it directly you could create it inside an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to avoid leaking it's name into your current scope.

Comment: Be warned, older versions of IE conflate function *expressions* and function *statements*.  `(function doRequest(err, res) { ... })` actually defines `doRequest` in the global scope.

Comment: @cHao: Not in global scope, but it creates a second function object. See http://kangax.github.io/nfe/ for details (and screw IE, imho)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using backend node.js so IE not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a closure and reference an inner function you declare, like:

```
var obj = {
    a: (function () {
        var func = function() { //parent callback
            request.get(URL, function(err, res) {
                if (err == 209) {
                    func();
                }
            });
        };
        return func;
    }())
};
```

**Simplified DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UqMhK/

You would then call `obj.a();` like normal.

This allows you to keep your original structure and not have to name the anonymous function, but accomplishes what you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I think the best way for the code you posted should look something like this:

```
var stillALambda = function thatFunction(err, res) {
  request.get(URL, function(err, res) {
    if (err == 209) thatFunction();
  });
};
```

The function above is still a lambda, but now the outer function's scope contains a reference to itself in `thatFunction`. Thanks to the almighty power of closure, this can be used from within the inner function as well.